# My wireless card fails to automatically turn on sometimes?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I've been experiencing a strange issue sometimes with my desktop running Windows 7 Ultimate.  Once in a while, when I turn it on, my wireless card will not be detected at all and will not automatically connect to my home network.  After a few restarts, it will detect fine on startup and connect to the network.

When it does this and I try to connect, I immediately get a message stating "Windows was unable to connect to ".  ipconfig /release and /renew give me the message: `No operation can be performed on Wireless Network Connection while it has its media disconnected.`.  Sometimes, disabling and re-enabling the Wireless adapter from my Device Manager fixes it.  Sometimes, I just have to wait a few minutes and it will automatically try to connect and work.

Any idea what would cause this behavior?  Keep in mind it only happens **sometimes**.  Most of the time I can connect just fine on startup, but every so often it'll take about 15 minutes and several restarts before it will be turned on automatically.

Comment: My wireless card on my Asus notebook stops working after twenty minutes if it's running on battery, or if I hibernate. My only fix is Disable / Enable, or keeping it plugged in. I know this isn't an answer, but it's a sympathetic noise in your general direction to say it's not just you.

Comment: I've had randomish network drops on all sorts of hardware, laptops, desktops, etc.  As far as I can tell it's just a limitation of some wireless cards that every so often they drop a connection, don't work, etc.  If you find a clear answer for this I will be impressed.

Comment: You should probably say what kind of machine and wireless card they are.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson Agreed, Please provide more info for us.